# invoke - p/invoke

Tags: .net, pinvoke, invoke

what is the difference between BeginInvoke/EndInvoke and P/invoke?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They only have the verb "invoke" in common.  Generically, invoke == call.  The p in pinvoke means "platform", the pinvoke marshaller is a chunk of code inside the CLR that knows how to properly call native (platform specific) code.

BeginInvoke is a heavily overloaded method name that starts an asynchronous method call.  The compiler automatically generates one for every delegate type.  Along with Invoke and EndInvoke.  They are auto-generated so their arguments match the delegate declaration.  A BeginInvoke method is also used by Winforms and WPF, respectively the Control and Dispatcher classes.  Quite a different animal from a delegate's BeginInvoke() method, although it does start something asynchronously.

Comment: what do you mean when you write that Winform is the Control class?

Comment: Winforms has the Control class, it has a BeginInvoke() method.  WPF has the Dispatcher class, it has a BeginInvoke() method.

Comment: Thanks, what is an asynchronous method call?

Comment: The opposite of a synchronous call, the normal case where your code doesn't continue until the method finished its job.

Comment: what is Invoke, is it a synchronous call?  and who calls the BeginInvoke created for a delegate, the delegate instance or another method?

Comment: Yes.  Your code does.  This could potentially be a never ending comment trail.  Please do try to formulate a question.

Answer (score 3):

`BeginInvoke/EndInvoke` are used in [asynchronous programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb.aspx) to invoke a delegate on another thread. [`P/invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx) is used to call unmanaged code.

Comment: `BeginInvoke` does not necessarily use a thread pool thread, that depends on implementation (take `Control.BeginInvoke` as example).