# What does it mean to say WPF has the Dispatcher class?

Tags: .net, wpf, dispatcher

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906674/invoke-p-invoke/4907309#4907309) wrote that WPF has the [Dispatcher class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx)

What does that mean?

Comment: Can you supply a link to the article so that we can have a little context for the question?

Comment: I believe he's referring to [a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906674/invoke-p-invoke/4907309#4907309).

Comment: If that's the case, all that Hans means is that WPF contains a class called `Dispatcher` that uses the `BeginInvoke` method. WinForms has a class called `Control` that uses it.

Comment: @Cody Gray, that's a slightly misleading way of putting it. Neither the `Dispatcher` class nor the `Control` class *uses* a `BeginInvoke` method; they both *define* (implement) a method with that name.

Comment: @stakx: Fair enough. Your way sounds better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WPF framework does include a Dispatcher class, which is used for synchronization as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx).